# MongoDB query result as loop controller

Tags: javascript, loops, synchronous

I need to assign random number to object field then check if there is such object in database. If not save it else assign new random value and check db again and so on. I know that the problem is caused by synchronism and I have no clue how to solve it.

```
while (controller = 0) {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    Model.findOne({'x': x}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!err && !result) controller = 1;
        else controller = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: What is your intention? Your code looks like *"I want to find the first item that matches"*, but there are nicer ways to do that. What do you really want to do?

Comment: my intention is to save object to database if there is no same object in database already, and if there is, change value and try again

Comment: So your intention is to save a completely random object to the database? What for?

Comment: Yes, random and Unique. The reason is not important.

Comment: Well, if the reason is not important and "random and unique" is your criterion, how about using GUIDs?

Comment: because the random value is actually 3 values representing coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUTION:** I don't know details of your case, but your approach can significantly reduce performance. Especially with big MAX_VALUE for random number.

To solve you problem with asynchronous callback, you can define a function and call it recursively:

```
function saveIfNotExists() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    Model.findOne({'x': x}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!result) {
            // save object here
        } else {
            saveIfNotExists();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using MongoDB's upserts?

Basically, this performs an update of the document if it exists, otherwise inserts a new one. So effectively, you could update the document's property to itself if it exists, otherwise, insert the value as a new document if it does not already exist.

I cannot comment on performance of upserts, but I would think one database hit would be better than the two required to first check existence and then the second to do an insert.

Comment: I don't want to update existing document. If there is document with same value i need to get new random value and try inserting it as new unique document.

Comment: So I suppose that after a successful insert, you need to know what the random number is that was just inserted?

Comment: No, I know the number before I try to insert it.

Comment: I realize that you have the number, but was asking if you need to do something after performing an insert. In other words, do you need to do something specific with the random number that was inserted (therefore did not previously exist in the collection).If not, then performing an upsert is valid:if the number exists in a document in the collection, then the document is updated, setting the value in question to itself and thereby not changing the document. Otherwise, if a document does not exist with the particular value (being the random number generated), then a new document is inserted